# Switching the source for the packages

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Previous, my sources were these:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
```

I changed them to point to these:

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
```

The rational for change is to fasten the updates as the original sources were pretty slow for me.

Is it OK? The later repos seems to be used for bleeding-edge-repos and in general in addition to the replaced ones.

Source : http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The Khali Web page is very clear: *If you have a need for bleeding edge repositories, you can add the following entry. Do not add this repo “for the heck of it” – it’s called “bleeding edge” for a reason. Packages in this repository are NOT manually maintained (they are auto-generated), and are low priority in general.* You are running a considerable risk, if you do not know what you are doing.

Comment: http.kali.org is very slow while updating package. Wanted to find an alternate source.

Comment: Between, I am not choosing kali-bleeding-edge, I am still selected kali, only thing changed is source. Will this still pull out the bleeding-edge packages ? Source : http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/

Comment: No, that will have no effect whatsoever on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion was whether I am pulling from the kali-bleeding-edge, but as I am only switched to the locations of source package but still selected to pull the packages from kali, I wont be getting kali-bleeding-edge packages.